# A pitcher given the loss despite others allowing the winning runs - how?

Tags: rules, baseball

Tanaka was charged with the loss on 26 May 2017 when he allowed 1 run in 7.1 innings, then the bullpen allowed another 3 runs.

The Yankees scored 1 run in the bottom of the ninth. Shouldn't the pitcher who allowed the second run take the loss, not Tanaka?

Answer (score 5):

Conditions for awarding wins and losses in MLB are listed in the [Official Baseball Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf).  This is covered by Rule 9 (specifically 9.17(d)) which directs the official scorer.

> 9.17
>
> [...]
>
> (d) A losing pitcher is a pitcher who is responsible for the run that gives the winning team a lead that the winning team does not
>   relinquish.

So even though other pitchers may have performed worse or the team scored some runs after the fact, because Tanaka allowed the other team to take the lead and that lead was never relinquished, he is credited with the loss.